# Ionic 3 first rootPage on condition

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want my Ionic 3 app to check a locally stored variable right after the app is loaded (after splash), and then set the `rootPage` accordingly. I need to know where should I put the code for this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [conference Ionic template](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app).

You can create the app directly from the ionic CLI:

```
ionic start conference-demo conference
```

The relevant part is in the `src/app/app.component.ts` file:

```
this.storage.get('myStoredVariable')
    .then((myStoredVariable) => {
        if (myStoredVariable) {
            this.rootPage = customPage;
        } else {
            this.rootPage = defaultPage;
        }
    });
}
```